# When deploying a contract what is important (overall contract/wasm size or amount of functions etc) to not get transaction took too long

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, development, cpu, contract-development

when I try to deploy the system.contract I sometimes get transaction took too long with the new eosio version 1.8.1.

Now I would like to know on which part of a contract do I need to pay attention to. The overall size of the contract/wasm file or the amount of function and tables in it.

thx helping

Comment: Are you having specific issues with deploying a smart contract? You should not be running into transaction timeouts for deploying contracts unless they are absolutely huge. Is this on mainnet, testnet, or your local network?

Comment: I run ubuntu on a windows hyper-v virtual machine (which has 2 cores)  and the problem is only when I want to deploy the standard eosio.system contract and also after  I added 2-4 new functions and 2 little struct/tables to the eosio.system contract that I can not deploy the contract in 15ms which is as I believe the max trx time on the mainnet. 

I don't know how much the virtual machine weights into that but I think an aws is somewhat also a virtual machine but could have faster cpu's as mine amd 5 year old fx8320.